# Why is Cauchy the default prior for both testing and estimation?

Tags: self-study, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian, uninformative-prior, cauchy-distribution

Assume that a data set follows a normal distribution and the prior and posterior both have a normal-gamma distribution. When we are performing Bayesian analysis but don't want any subjective choice of prior to affect the posterior we are recommended to choose the NormalGamma(0, 0, 0, -1) which is a special case of the reference prior, independent Jeffreys prior. It's said that it is because the prior is invariant to the units of the data.

But when we are considering a non-conjugate prior, the Cauchy distribution is said to be prefered both for testing and estimation. I learned that Cauchy distribution is a special case of a student t distribution with $v_0$ as 1. But I wonder why Cauchy distribution was recommended by Sir Harold Jefferys as a default objective prior for both estimation and testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image] [image]

The Cauchy prior was suggested by [Jeffreys](https://amzn.to/2O3IY6K) *solely* for testing. On the basis (Chapter V, Section 2) of giving all the mass to the alternative when the observation is not zero and the sample variance zero, as shown in my slides above (taken from a [seminar series](https://www.slideshare.net/xianblog/theory-of-probability-revisited) I gave on Jeffreys' book), where (in Jeffreys' notations) $K$ denotes the Bayes factor, $f(\cdot)$ the prior under the alternative. I find the argument very limited and carrying very little strenghth when compared with Jeffreys' notion of non-testing reference priors.